# English to Greek Translator

Tags: windows, translation

I want to translate text from English to Greek.

Requirements:

- Takes English text (copy-pasted) as input, outputs Greek text.
- Runs on Windows, or online webapp
- Preferably free, but can pay up to 100 euros

I have tried Google Translate, but the results weren't very good.

Comment: What is your budget?

Comment: I would like a free one, but anything up to 80-100 euros would do

Comment: When you say "a document", do you mean some text that you can copy paste into a text area on a website or into a field in a program?

Comment: A text I can copy and paste

Comment: Google Translate is usually hard to beat! It's almost a gold standard in machine translation...

Comment: Modern or ancient Greek?

Comment: I would prefer Modern

Comment: There are [several other English-to-Greek translators](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=greek+english+translation+software). Which one do you prefer?